# Merge the common rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the following output

```
Code  Manager    Employee
1      A          Emp1
1      A          Emp2   
1      A          Emp3  
2      B          Emp4
2      B          Emp5
```

but I want result as

```
Code   Manager    Employee
1       A          Emp1
                   Emp2
                   Emp3
2       B          Emp4
                   Emp5
```

Code and manager columns should not repeat.It should be blank.

Comment: I think you cannot do that with a query...

Comment: are you REALLY sure that this have sense? please explain your context / why are you doing this

Comment: If you leave the columns blank, how can you tell that `Emp2` is for `Code=1` and `Manager=A`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, author needs such srtange output for producing some specific user interface. In this case it makes sense to stay with first result set and implement displaying logic in client code

Comment: SQL is for getting the data and formatting it some, but the program which uses the query does the presentation.

Comment: The result would not be a relation (e.g. row ordering) so it is not best suited to SQL. I suggest you use a report writing tool to perform such formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case when Code = lag(Code) over(order by Code, Manager, Employee)
         then null
         else Code
       end as Code,
       case when Manager = lag(Manager) over(order by Code, Manager, Employee)
         then null
         else Manager
       end as Manager,
       Employee
from YourTable Y
order by Y.Code, Y.Manager, Y.Employee
```

Try on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97b48/9)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like Access or Crystal Reports to do this sort of formatting. Its not possible in plain SQL.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible by SQL. You should manually loop the data in code after receiving it from database.

**Edit**

After comments by Vashh and Lieven, I realized that it is possible. So if he needs for display purpose he can either use Func (suggested by Vaassh), Join with null (s. by Lieven) or may be loop and add to datagridview or table or whatever he wants to use.

Comment: You can do this with a transact-sql function, but it seems logically incorrect

Comment: It is possible but not pretty. It would involve joining with itself and using a case statement to determine if code and manager should output their values or just NULL.

Comment: Yes I completely forgot that. I think if he only wants for better display purpose hey may choose either func or join as suggested by you guys.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of it, following is one way to do it but in the end, this is better done in the end-user application

```
;WITH YourTable (Code, Manager, Employee) AS(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (1, 'A', 'Emp1')
        , (1, 'A', 'Emp2')
        , (1, 'A', 'Emp3')
        , (2, 'B', 'Emp4')
        , (2, 'B', 'Emp5')
    ) a (b, c, d)       
)
, q AS (
    SELECT  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code, Manager, Employee), *
    FROM    YourTable
)
SELECT  Code = CASE WHEN q1.Code = q2.Code THEN NULL ELSE q1.Code END
        , Manager = CASE WHEN q1.Code = q2.Code THEN NULL ELSE q1.Manager END
        , q1.Employee
FROM    q q1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN q q2 ON q1.rn = q2.rn + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking for an answer in Oracle, but maybe this SQL Server example will help you (if you really, really need to do it like this and not in a reporting environment):

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(
  Code     INT,
  Manager  CHAR(1),
  Employee VARCHAR(4))

INSERT @TBL VALUES (1,'A','Emp1')
INSERT @TBL VALUES (1,'A','Emp2')
INSERT @TBL VALUES (1,'A','Emp3')
INSERT @TBL VALUES (2,'B','Emp4')
INSERT @TBL VALUES (2,'B','Emp5')

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Code
                ,Manager
                ,Employee
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Code) rownum
         FROM   @TBL)
SELECT CASE curr.Code
         WHEN prev.Code THEN ''
         ELSE CAST(curr.Code AS VARCHAR(20))
       END AS _Code
       ,CASE curr.Manager
          WHEN prev.Manager THEN ''
          ELSE curr.Manager
        END AS _Manager
       ,curr.Employee
FROM   cte curr
       LEFT JOIN cte prev
         ON curr.rownum = prev.rownum + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using SQL Server 2005/2008, you can achieve this with the following.

```
declare @table table (
Code int,
Manager Varchar(1),
Employee varchar(10)
)

insert into @table values
(1,'A','Emp1'),
(1,'A','Emp2'),
(1,'A','Emp3'),
(2,'A','Emp4'),
(2,'A','Emp5')

select * from @table
select
case when number=1 then Code else null end as Code,
case when number=1 then Manager else null end as Manager,
employee
from (
select *,
row_number() over (partition by code, manager order by code,manager) as number
from @table
) x
```

Which will give you:

```
(5 row(s) affected)
Code        Manager Employee
----------- ------- ----------
1           A       Emp1
1           A       Emp2
1           A       Emp3
2           A       Emp4
2           A       Emp5

(5 row(s) affected)

Code        Manager employee
----------- ------- ----------
1           A       Emp1
NULL        NULL    Emp2
NULL        NULL    Emp3
2           A       Emp4
NULL        NULL    Emp5

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Didn't see the Oracle tag :-(

Answer (score 0):

Done:)

You can change NULL values to '' if you want to.

```
WITH 
CTE1 AS (
SELECT DISTINCT [Code], [Manager], 
(   SELECT TOP 1 Employee 
    FROM [dbo].[table] t2 
    WHERE t1.Code = t2.Code AND t1.Manager = t2.Manager 
    ORDER BY Employee) AS [Employee]
FROM [dbo].[table] t1)
,
CTE2 AS (
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table]
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * FROM CTE1)

SELECT * FROM CTE1
UNION
SELECT NULL as Code, NULL as Manager, Employee
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

My SQL*Plus is a little rusty but if that's the tool that you're using then it should be fairly simple but using the `BREAK` command.

As mentioned in one of the comments about, this is best left to your reporting tool rather than doing in the actual SQL because an individual row without all the values doesn't make any sense outside the context of the result set.

```
BREAK on code on manager

SELECT code, manager, employee
FROM yourTable y
order by code, manager;
```

Please not that my SQL*Plus is a little rusty so this might not work exactly but details of the `BREAK` command can be found [in the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#sthref1252).